# How to end a shell script?

Tags: shell-script

I'm partway writing a script on Linux and I wanted to add an extra bit and ask the user whether they want to quit the program, can anyone help me in figuring out how I can do this?

Comment: you can exit as "exit 0".

Comment: But how to I ask the user whether they want it to exit?

Comment: In whatever way you want. `echo -n "Do you want to stop? "; read answer; if [ "$answer" = y ]; then exit 0; fi`

Comment: Is it that you want the user to be able to stop the script whenever he wants during the run, without having to ask for it?  If so, the user can always do a CTRL-C that you can catch with `trap` to perform any housekeeping.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain exactly what you need. Mention that you want to ask the user whether or not to exit for example. @wurtel you may as well make that into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
read -p "Do you want to continue? (y/N) " ANS
    # if not, do something else, otherwise fall out the bottom
    [ "$ANS" = "y" -o "$ANS" = "Y" ] && {
            # commands here what to do if we stick around
            echo "OK, we will continue"
            # better put something else to do here or we'll fall out anyway.
            }
```